# How to select option if value contains string

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to select option if value contains particular string.

```
<select>
    <option value="sunday,1523">Sunday</option>
    <option value="monday,1583">Monday</option>
</select>
```

Need to select option contains 1583 value.
I tried, but not working.

```
$("select option:contains(1583)").prop("selected","selected")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are searching for **Attribute Contains Selector**

```
[name*=”value”]
```

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

```js
$("select option[value*=1583]").prop("selected", true)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
  <option value="sunday,1523">Sunday</option>
  <option value="monday,1583">Monday</option>
</select>
```

**References**

https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Answer (score 3):

Vanilla JS solution using [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var options = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("select option"))
options.filter(option => option.value.includes("1583"))[0].selected = true;
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="sunday,1523">Sunday</option>
  <option value="monday,1583">Monday</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use JavaScript's built-in **includes()** method.

```js
let select = document.querySelector("select");

for(let i=0; i<select.options.length; i++){
    if(select.options[i].value.includes('1583')){
    select.options[i].selected = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option value="sunday,1523">Sunday</option>
    <option value="monday,1583">Monday</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Attribute selector `[value]` that ends with `$=`

```js
const num = "1583";

$(`option[value$="${num}"]`).prop("selected", true);
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="sunday,1523">Sunday</option>
  <option value="monday,1583">Monday</option>
</select>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//if contain specific word '1583'
$("select option[value~='1583']").prop("selected", true)

//if contain word '1583'
$("select option[value*='1583']).prop("selected", true)

//if ending with '1583'
$("select option[value$='1583']).prop("selected", true)
```

Remember, the difference between prop() and attr()
eg:`prop("selected", true)`, `attr("selected", "selected")`